# All AppServiceConsoleLogs being shown as Error level in Azure Application Insights regardless of log level specified in message

Tags: python, logging, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

We have an app service which is logging to Azure Application Insights. When logs from within the App Service are aggregated in the AppServiceConsoleLogs table, they are all listed as "Error" level despite setting the log level as Info from within our app. Has anyone experienced this or know how to fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the logs for application insights by using the below code.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import logging
from applicationinsights import TelemetryClient
from applicationinsights.requests import WSGIApplication
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse
from fastapi.middleware.trustedhost import TrustedHostMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

instrumentation_key = 'your appinsights instrumentationkey'  
telemetry_client = TelemetryClient(instrumentation_key)

app.add_middleware(TrustedHostMiddleware, allowed_hosts=["*"])

console_logger = logging.getLogger('console_logs')
console_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
console_logger.addHandler(console_handler)

@app.get("/")
async def hello():
    telemetry_client.track_trace("Information log (App Insights)", severity='Information')
    telemetry_client.track_trace("Warning log (App Insights)", severity='Warning')
    telemetry_client.track_trace("Error log (App Insights)", severity='Error')
    
    console_logger.info("Information log (Console)")
    console_logger.warning("Warning log (Console)")
    console_logger.error("Error log (Console)")
    telemetry_client.track_trace("Custom log (App Insights)", severity='Custom')
    
    telemetry_client.flush()
    return PlainTextResponse("Hello, World!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

The status of above code in local:

[image]

**Logs in applicationinsights:**

I am able to get the logs in application insights, and the correct severity level is also shown.

[image]

[image]

I am getting the appservice logs and also the loglevel status.
**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified, our application is a FastAPI app.

Comment: @NickPetzold, updated the solution by using FastAPI app.